# What's wrong with this python timezone conversion?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, timezone, dst

I want to convert a datetime with `US/Eastern` timezone to `Budapest/Europe` timezone this way:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

ET = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
CET = pytz.timezone('Europe/Budapest')

time = datetime(2013, 04, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=ET)
newTime = time.astimezone(CET)
```

This results newTime being: `datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 18, 7, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)`, but it should be `2013,04,18,6,0` according to [time.is](http://time.is/compare/0000_18_Apr_2013_in_ET/Budapest) and [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20130418T00&p1=179&p2=50) converters. What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the Daylight Saving Time issue. The time passed to `datetime` is in the `ET`, not `EDT`, hence the result.

Take a look at `pytz` documentation, the preferred way is to use `localize` method, rather than passing `tzinfo`. You'll get the expected result if you amend your code to use the following line:

```
time = ET.localize(datetime(2013, 04, 18, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Good answer.  I wouldn't have thought of that! Time to brush up on my python skillz. :)

Answer (score 0):

`US/Eastern` is an alias.  Perhaps pytz treats it as fixed to EST instead of EDT?  I'm not sure.  But try `America/New_York` and see if that is better.

Comment: It is the same with `America/New_York` ! I suspect there is something to do with daylight saving time